# How to create a function which can test the random Word cooccurrence of another function?

Tags: f#

So my team and I have created a function, wordMarkovChain, which generates a random string with nWords words, whose word-pairs are distributed according to the cooccurrence histogram wCooc.
Now we wanted to create a function which will test the newly created wordMarkovChain, so I can confirm that it's working as it should. 
The function, diffw2, which compares two cooccurrence histograms as the average sum of squared differences, needs to take in two parameters, c1 and c2, of type wordCooccurrences and return a double, where c1 and c2 are two cooccurrence histograms of M elements such that c1(i, j) is the number
of times word number i is found following word number j.

The math behind the function should look like this: 1/M^2 * Summation from i=0 to M-1 Summation from i=0 to M-1 (c1(i, j) - c2(i, j))^2.

Sorry, I can't post a picture:(
Our two types which we have created seems to be the problem. c1 and c2 can have a different length but the type wordHistogram inside the type wordCoocurence can also have a different length.
The question is, how can we create such a function? 
We tried with for loops, but we think it needs to be a recursive function. We are quite new to the whole concept of programming and are looking for some guidance. Please bear in mind that we do not possess vast knowledge of F#, especially not their in build functions.

**CODE**

```
// Types  
type wordHistogram = (string * int) list
type wordCooccurrences = (string * wordHistogram) list

let diffw2 (c1 : wordCooccurrences) (c2 : wordCooccurrences) : double = 
  let mutable res = 0 
  let z1, z2 = c1 |> List.unzip
  let z3, z4 = c2 |> List.unzip 
  let m1 = c1 |> List.length
  let m2 = c2 |> List.length
  let m = m1 + m2

  for i in 0 .. (m - 1) do
    for j in 0 .. (m - 1) do
      for k in 0 .. ((z2.[j] |> List.length) - 1) do
        res <- res + (snd z2.[j].[k] - snd z4.[j].[k]) * (snd z2.[j].[k] - snd z4.[j].[k])
  (1.0 / (float(m * m))) * float(res)
```

Comment: What's the actual problem or question?

Comment: Are `c1` and `c2` expected to be the same length?

Comment: How do we make diffw2 work with our current setup? Atm. we get outOfBoundException and if we change something we get a bunch of other errors. Someone told us we should use recursive functions, but I just can't see how that would work. Sorry for not being completely clear :(

Comment: No. c1, and c2 can have different length, that's why we are getting outOfBoundException atm.

Comment: @CainAlthea, in that case note that you are looping up to `m`, which is the sum of `m1` and `m2`, but you are accessing elements from `z2` and `z4` which are guaranteed to have less elements than `m`. Also, `i` is never used at all. Try getting the above to work, and I will help you translate it to more idiomatic F# code.

Comment: @ChechyLevas I just edited the question, with more details. Thank you btw for trying!

Comment: @CainAlthea, we're getting there. But note that neither `c1`, nor `c2` can ever be indexed up to `m-1` because you have defined `m` to be the sum of the lengths of `c1` and `c2`, which by definition will result in an out of bounds error

Comment: @ChechyLevas Yea, I can see that now. Thank you for pointing that out, but I think it's a mistake from our side. M should not be the sum of the length of both c1 and c2. I think that was just us trying to change the function a bit so we could get closer to the result, but in reality we just went further, and further away from it :(

Comment: @CainAlthea rewrite then, as best you can, and then I will help you to translate it to normal looking F#. As I mentioned earlier, try not to use loops and mutable values.

Comment: @ChechyLevas we will try to rewrite the function so it makes more sense, to what we are actually asking. Might take some time :D

Comment: @CainAlthea It would help a lot if you could provide an example of `c1` and `c2` and the expected result given those inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you closer to what you need. This could instead be done using recursive functions, but I usually prefer to use built-in higher-order functions like `fold` or `fold2` when they can do the job. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold2%5B't1%2C't2%2C'state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D

Each call of `List.fold2` receives an "accumulator" with an initial value (or "state") of 0.0. This accumulator is passed to the lambda function in the parameter named "acc". As the lambda is applied to each element of the two input lists, it adds the intermediate result to that `acc` value, which is then returned as the result of the `List.fold2` call.

```
type wordHistogram = (string * int) list
type wordCooccurrences = (string * wordHistogram) list

let diffw2 (c1 : wordCooccurrences) (c2 : wordCooccurrences) = 
  let m1 = c1 |> List.length
  let m2 = c2 |> List.length
  let m = m1 + m2

  let res =
      (0.0, c1, c2) |||>
      List.fold2 (fun acc (_str1, hist1) (_str2, hist2) ->
        let intermedRes =
            (0.0, hist1, hist2) |||>
            List.fold2 (fun acc (_str1, freq1) (_str2, freq2) ->
                let diff = float (freq1 - freq2)
                acc + diff * diff
            )
        acc + intermedRes
      )

  (1.0 / float(m * m)) * res
```

Comment: I think @Chechy Levas's answer will probably do the same thing. If performance matters, then there might be a difference between the two answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do the following

```
let diffw2_  (c1 : wordCooccurrences) (c2 : wordCooccurrences) = 
    List.zip c1 c2
    |> List.sumBy (fun ((_, w1), (_, w2)) ->
        List.zip w1 w2
        |> List.sumBy (fun ((_,i1), (_,i2)) ->
            (float (i1 - i2)) ** 2.0
        )
    ) |> (fun totalSumOfSquares -> totalSumOfSquares / (c1 |> List.length |> float))
```

This just returns the average square differences between corresponding elements of c1 and c2. It assumes that c1 and c2 have the same structure.

With F# (and functional programming in general), you typically avoid using mutable variables and for loops, in favor of pure functions.

Comment: I realize this is not what is intended but the question is difficult to parse as it stands.

Comment: Give me a second to rephrase the question. I just realized that I was not specific, my bad.